# R List combinations of items with count of these

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to see how many records I have for combinations of Products. Some Accounts have a couple of different products, some have 3 or 4. I've done a group by, which gives the number of Products attached to each Account:

```
test <- data %>%
  unique() %>%
  group_by(ACCOUNT) %>% summarise(number = n())
```

What I am trying to do next is group the Product permutations so I have a count for each of a+b, b+c, a+b+c, a+b+m, m+n etc.
I don't expect all the possible permutations to exist, but I don't know what the biggest number of products combined is - that's one of the things I'm trying to work out. (although it's probably about 5 or 6)

```
Edited to add sample data
| Account | Product |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1    | a           |
| 1  | b            |
|1  |c  |
|2  |a  |
|2   |c  |
|3  |a  |
|3  |c  |
|4  |a  |
|4  |b|
```

Desired Results - each unique combination to be counted separately.

```
| Product combo | Count |
| -------- | -------------- |
| ab  | 1           |
| ac  | 2            |
|abc |1  |
```

Comment: If you posted a small reproducible data set ppl would be able to help you

Comment: I assume you are interested in what products are bought together (perhaps not), but you have to provide us with sample data (as mentioned already), but also need some more information on how you define your groups. For example `a+b+c` ones should they be counted as well in `a+b` , `b+c`, `a+c` ? So besides a small sample data set, also provide the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a `;` separator because it seems nicer, but here is a `dplyr` version:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Account) %>%
  summarize(combo = paste(sort(Product), collapse = ";"), .groups = "drop") %>%
  count(combo)
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#   combo Count
#   <chr> <int>
# 1 a;b       1
# 2 a;b;c     1
# 3 a;c       2
```

---

Using this data:

```
df = read.table(text = ' Account  Product 
 1     a           
 1   b            
1  c  
2  a  
2   c  
3  a  
3  c  
4  a  
4  b', header = T)
```